# Help reverse engineering an RS485 adaptor

Tags: pcb, level-shifting, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer a RS485 shield for a Raspberry Pi 3 that was part of a consumer appliance; I'm trying to repurpose it for other projects, but I wonder if it has ever worked. I don't have access to the software that used it.

The shield uses a 75HVD12 transceiver ([datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn75hvd10.pdf)) with 3.3V D and DE pins for transmission and R and /RE pins for receiving. D, R and DE are connected to the Pi's UART (respectively to TXD, RXD and RTS), which is all good. However, /RE is puzzling.

The shield uses only THT components. In the picture below, pink is the tracing of the front side, while red and green are the copper layers. (The two airwires are due to Kicad not understanding 0 ohm resistors).

[image: current state of reverse engineering]

The silkscreen has space for 7 resistors and 1 transistor, but in practice only 3 resistors are used and two of them are 0 ohm:

- the zero ohm resistor on the right connects the DE pin to the RTS pin and that's okay
- a 10k resistor on the left is a pull-up to VCC for the /RE pin
- the zero ohm resistor on the left connects the /RE pin to the bottom unpopulated resistor and from there to the unpopulated transistor (?)

The last one seems just wrong.  It would be somewhat weird, but feasible, to use a zero ohm resistor to connect /RE to GND (using the second slot from the top), but then you wouldn't need the pull-up resistor.  It would also be even easier to connect DE and /RE together, but there is nothing on the board that allows that.

My best guess is that the board was adjusted from a version that used a 5V transceiver. That version would adjust the Raspberry Pi's TXD from 3.3V to 5V (using the transistor) and the opposite for RXD (using a voltage divider, hence the empty resistors). But the conversion was botched somehow and the software was changed to not use the component.

Cutting the two resistors on the left and soldering a jumper wire between DE and /RE would probably be the easiest way to fix the mess, but I'm wondering if my guess makes sense or I am missing something.

Comment: Did the original application require responses? Maybe it only sent commands.

Comment: It's a data logger and, based on the manufacturer specifications, it uses Modbus so it requires responses. But maybe they switched to an external converter (e.g. RS485->USB). It would be as easy as replacing ttyAMA0 with ttyUSB0 in the sources...

Comment: I'll add that other places in the board use a 10K+15K voltage divider to convert inputs from 5V to 3.3V, so that part of the theory might hold. The routing of /RE doesn't make sense though.

Comment: Schematic is needed. You haven't shown where the data lines go.

Comment: The data lines go to the Raspberry Pi TXD and RXD pins, I added that to the question. I don't have a schematic yet, I'm trying to make one.

Comment: @PaoloBonzini Please draw a a schematic

Comment: I would follow Figure 27